# Substitute variable inside manipulate

Tags: manipulate, replacement, symbolic, symbols

Consider the following piece of code

```
dbh_m := 100*dbh 
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, Sin[dbh]]},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}], {dbh, 0, 1}
 ]
```

What it does is to plot a 3D sphere of variable radius. If now I modify it like this

```
dbh_m := 100*dbh 
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{Sphere[{0.5, 0.5, 0.5}, Sin[dbh_m]]},
  PlotRange -> {{0, 1}, {0, 1}, {0, 1}}], {dbh, 0, 1}
 ]
```

It stops working.
So my question is, is there a way to let Manipulate know of the "outer context". Or in other terms can I make manipulate interpret the variables?

Comment: The `dbh` inside the manipulate is actually a local symbol, so `dbhM`(you really should avoid underscores in variable names!)  doesn't 'see' manipulate's `dbh` (which actually becomes `dbh$123213` or something locally). What you should do is define `dbhM[dbh_]:=100*dbh` and then plot `...Sin[dbhM[dbh]]...` inside the manipulate. You might be interested in this post [about scoping constructs](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/559/what-are-the-use-cases-for-different-scoping-constructs)

Comment: Your doubts are addressed in linked topic. Except the problem with `dbh_m` name which is a beginner mistake. Let me know if you disagree with closing.

Comment: I'm ok with closing it. I think having a kind of alias would be more neat than using a function. But I understand the scoping issue...